# load an xml into the Class View

Tags: android

I am new in android
I have created 2 classes.first extends activity and 2nd extends View.
I want to add buttons,image Views etc. into the second class
How can I do this?

Comment: So... where's the code you did? How are you trying to achieve that? I feel you don't completely understand the android basis for UI creation, but anyway we need to know more before helping you, don't you think so?

Comment: i know how to add the widgets in activity(using xml,setContentView(R.layout.main))

Comment: But I want to add these things into a class View......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **inflate** in the View class, this allows you to inflate an arbitrary XML-file which is then added to a specific ViewGroup:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context, int, android.view.ViewGroup)

Usage:

```
View.inflate(context, R.id.my_layout_file, myViewGroup);
```

Comment: can you provide a simple example. I will be greatful to you.please.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820401/how-to-load-an-xml-inside-a-view-in-android/3820640#3820640