# How to load an XML inside a View in android?

Tags: android

I am having a class that extends View. I have another class that extends activity and I want to add the first class to be loaded inside the activity class.
I tried the following code

```
package Test2.pack;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Test2 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static view v;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        try{
            v = (view) View.inflate(Test2.this, R.layout.main2, null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(" ERR " + e.getMessage()+e.toString());
        }       
    }
}

class view extends View{
    public view(Context context) {
        super(context);     
    }   
}
```

Comment: I just want to load a custom view to the class which extends View inside my class that extends Activity.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok tried this, and realized that it doesn't work. The problem is, that the View class does not have methods for adding child views. Child views should only be added to `ViewGroups`. Layouts, such as `LinearLayout`, extend `ViewGroup`. So instead of extending View, you need to extend for example `LinearLayout`.

Then, in your XML, reference to the layout with:

```
<my.package.MyView
    android:id="@+id/CompId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Then in your custom class, inflate and add:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.initComponent(context);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.initComponent(context);
    }


    private void initComponent(Context context) {

         LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foobar, null, false);
         this.addView(v);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... could've simplified some things. initComponent(Context context) could just contain: inflate(context, R.layout.foobar, this); and the effect would be the same.

Comment: you can edit your own answers to improve them. Adding this as  a comment means it could be missed by everyone that reads this answer.