# Is it possible to make a sample android view (Card View) in XML and store it in a a variable then use it again and again?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to use a cardView having some internal structure at multiple places. Is there a way to make a cardView in an extra layout XML file and then store it in a variable programmatically and later use that variable to show that cardView where ever I want by adding it dynamically?

I want to make that cardView sample in XML as it much easier to edit there.
Currently, when I try above method I get an error "view already has a parent" for obvious reasons. I can definitely copy paste code but i would like to know if there is any smart way.

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if you need any other detail or find it hard to understand my question.

Comment: What if you called the `removeView(View view)` method on the parent that you initially attached it to?

Comment: @zsmb13 but that would limit me to displaying it only once at a time.

Comment: try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3820640/4800774 , that should work

Comment: Oh, if you need multiple instances at the same time, you'll have to inflate each one separately.

Comment: @zsmb13 I want to add same cardView in a LinearLayout ,say 10 times. I don't want to create cardView programmatically because visual editing is easier so I chose XML. To inflate separately i need different cardViews declared in XML.

Comment: @RuiCardoso I don't understand how that can help me. It might have if I had been creating cardView dynamically rather than in XML.

Comment: Using that way, you create your card on XML like you want, then you call          `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout, null, false);`

This will create your card view using the layout on `cardview_layout`

Comment: @RuiCardoso I will try that and let you know later.

Comment: @RuiCardoso Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it.......

have a separate xml for your card view...........let say `card.xml`

in your main/activity xml make/select a parent layout (Linear / Relative) where you want to place it......or may be different view..

```
    private void addMyCard(){
         ParentLayoutType parent=(ParentLayoutType) findViewById(R.id.idGivenToParent);
         View yourCardViewName= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.card,null);
         parent.addView(yourCardViewName);
    }
```

Hope it helps